# pagina web con node js express,me logeo por localhost, pero por el ip fijo de la maquina no, no se si es el codigo o el xamp q debo hacer?

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, express

La pagina sale en todos los dispositivos de mi red local .. el problema esta en que no funciona la base de datos osea no me deja iniciar sección por el ip fijo de la pc y por localhost si, no se si es en el código que debo cambiar algo o es el xampp que le fata alguna configuración.

Comment: Nosotros tampoco sabemos si es el código o no... porque no lo has compartido. Revisa [ask] y recuerda hacer el [tour]